# Python.el and Python-mode: Documentation & Features

Tags: python, emacs

I have been reading about the [different Python packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670505/comparison-of-python-modes-for-emacs) available for Emacs for some time. However, I have never been able to find the official documentation of either package.

From what I understand, `python-mode` seems is hosted at launchpad, but the repository does not have a wiki nor a document explaining the features, etc. On the other hand, `python.el` comes with recent versions of Emacs, but I can't find a documentation walkthrough its features anywhere.

Also, do both of them support **step-by-step debugging** through `ipdb` `ipython`? Where can I find more information on this matter?

Comment: Read the commentaries of both libraries.  You can find these in a special comment section right at the beginning of these files.  At least for Emacs' built-in `python.el` this commentary is quite comprehensive and explains all features of the mode.

Answer (score 3):

Comments following `;;; Commentary` is a good starting point, as @lunaryorn suggested.  If you need setup read this part first.

But I think just start using it when your setup is done (for python.el, there is nothing to do if you use Emacs 24.3) is the best way to go through the features.

This is because Emacs is self-documenting editor.  You can read all document about Emacs in Emacs.  In Python buffer, use `<f1> b` (or `C-h` instead of `<f1>`) to see a list of command you can use (this is the list of features).  Each command is linked to the docstring of the command.  You can also open a menu using "Ctrl + Right Click" to see a list of command you can use in the buffer.  The document of `python-mode` function, which can be opened by `<f1> f python-mode RET`, may be another good starting point.  If you want to see documentation of some keybind, type `<f1> k KEY-BIND`.  There are more useful help commands.  See `<f1> <f1>` for more info.  These techniques are not specific to python-mode, so you can use them for python.el and python-mode.el.

Re ipdb:  python.el (and I guess python-mode.el also) can do it.  There is code snippet in `;;; Commentary` that you can use in Emacs configuration.

Comment: Thanks @tkf! When you mentioned `;;; Commentary` which file are you referring to? I am using the latest stable release of Emacs, but I could not find `python.el` in my Emacs installation (I only found `python.elc` and `python.el.gz` under `/path/to/emacs/share/emacs/24.3/lisp/progmodes`)

Comment: I mean `python.el.gz`.  Usually bundled libraries have source code in `*.el.gz` files, to save disk space.  BTW, easiest way to visit the file is to open `<f1> f python-mode RET` and click the link to the file.

Comment: @tkf As python.el provides `'python` --which is good, as python-mode.el provides `'python-mode`-- probably it's useful to write "python mode" when reffering to python.el's, while "python-mode" otherwise. Just an idea.

Comment: What I meant by python-mode is a major mode.  Both python.el and python-mode.el define a function called `python-mode`.  So I think there is no confusion.

Answer (score 2):

https://blueprints.launchpad.net/python-mode/+documentation

This offers some basic FAQs meanwhile.

python-mode.el is designed to support ipdb and all other debuggers right from the spot. Configuration as explained at top of python.el isn't needed, as these stuff is implemented. Most commands are self-explaining. Every command has a documentation string, which users will find useful for some features like `py-expression`. Also the return values are reported there.

To get an overview which commands exist, the menu is a good starting point.

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Menu-Bar.html

python-mode.el lists commands alongside with its explanations in directory "doc".

Read the comments as suggested. Afterwards maybe employ `outline-mode` or `hs-minor-mode` to take a tour of the symbols.

Finally: <kbd>M-x py- TAB</kbd>, resp. <kbd>M-x python- TAB</kbd> lists the implemented commands. Once the name is known, call it's docu Ctrl-h f

Both modes should work with IPython/ipdb.

Seem several howto's at the net.

Maybe consult this

http://gremu.net/blog/2010/using-ipythons-debugger-pdb-replacement/

Please file a bug-report if you can't make it work.

As for with python-mode.el:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode

As for python.el : M-x report-emacs-bug RET