# emacs Flycheck "Configured syntax checker python-flake8 cannot be used"

Tags: python, macos, emacs, homebrew, flycheck

New emacs/python user here.
I'm trying to set up `flycheck` to work (and use `flake8`).

This is the relevant part in my `init.el`:

```
(require 'python-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.py$" . python-mode))
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode)
```

When I open a `python` file my modeline includes `Py FlyC-`
From the [Flycheck manual](http://flycheck.github.io/Usage.html#Mode-line) I learned that this means `Flycheck` could not automatically find a suitable checker.

When I run `M-x flycheck-select-checker` and select `python-flake8` it returns:

```
Configured syntax checker python-flake8 cannot be used
```

I'm using OSX 10.9 with `homebrew` and these versions:

```
$ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 24.3.50.1
$ flake8 --version
2.1.0 (pep8: 1.4.6, pyflakes: 0.7.3, mccabe: 0.2.1) CPython 2.7.5 on Darwin
$ which flake8
/usr/local/bin/flake8
$ python --version
Python 2.7.5
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

As for the emacs packages, they are installed from `melpa` and `marmalade`

`python-mode` version: 6.0.10
`Flycheck` version: 0.15snapshot (package: 20131105.1502)

Any hints on how to get this working?

Comment: Do you have python-flake8 installed and on your path?

Comment: Not to the problem, but is there any specific reason, why you do not use the built-in Python mode?

Comment: @lunaryorn Because the internet tells me it's better. I'm not in the place to judge so I'm just following the herd here...

Comment: @jeroentbt It used to be, but the built-in Python mode was greatly improved in Emacs 24.3, so much of what you can read about this miss isn't true anymore.

Comment: @lunaryorn thanks for the heads-up. I'm going back to the default then... (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15672445/1929897)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do `M-: (executable-find "flake8")`.  If it says `nil`, add `/usr/local/bin` to your `exec-path`.

On OS X GUI applications do not inherit variables from the shell configuration and thus have a different `$PATH`.  Hence, being able to run `flake8` in the terminal doesn't imply, that Emacs is able to find it as well.

You may also want to look at the [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) package.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!
/usr/local/bin was indeed not in my `exec-path`, once set via customise everything worked.
I will probably be using `exec-path-from-shell`.

Comment: I think I ran into exact same problem, but how do I "add `/usr/local/bin` to `exec-path`"?

Comment: @LWZ By adding a corresponding `add-to-list` call to your `init.el`.