# emacs and python-mode: typical key bindings don't do anything?

Tags: emacs

I am finally getting close to a nice emacs environment, based off of [this](https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/minimal-emacs-configuration/blob/master/init.el) baseline. However, many of the python-emacs tutorials mention things like "`C-c C-c` to run this in a python shell", or "`C-c !`" to launch a python shell". For some reason I am not getting this functionality. I am getting `C-c C-c is undefined`. What does work is `M-x run-python`.

Why am I not getting the standard behavior? I am running emacs through cygwin, which has both python and ipython installed.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample `init.el` uses a different python mode than the tutorials you read.

[python-mode.el](https://gitlab.com/python-mode-devs/python-mode/blob/master/python-mode.el) (line 3147/3152) defines:

```
(define-key map [(control c)(control c)] 'py-execute-buffer)
(define-key map [(control c)(!)] 'py-shell)
```

but does not define `run-python`, which is instead defined in **python.el**, which is distributed with emacs since version 24.3. and is set as the default python mode in your referenced `init.el`.

See [EmacsWiki: Programming With Python Mode Dot El](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ProgrammingWithPythonModeDotEl) for setup instructions for **python-mode.el**.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between python.el and python-mode.el? Should I use them both or only one?

Comment: You you use only one major mode per buffer, for differences see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670505/comparison-of-python-modes-for-emacs

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. The `init.el` file I linked to references python-mode, and I have a python-mode folder (~/.emacs.d/elpa/python-mode-20150909.2301). Why is emacs using python.el? I'm trying to change my init.el file, but this is throwing me off.

Comment: C-c C-c should work. What is the contents of buffer when called? What says C-h v major-mode?

Comment: `C-c C-c is undefined.` And `C-h v major-mode` says `Its value is python-mode` when a .py file is in the buffer.

Comment: Aha! `C-c C-c` just worked. I didn't realize I had to have a python file open for it to work. However, `C-c !` is still not doing anything: `C-c ! [ret] is undefined`.

Comment: What says M-x describe-key... resp. C-h k C-c !

Comment: `C-c ! runs the command py-shell, which is an interactive compiled Lisp
function in `python-mode.el'.
It is bound to C-c !.
...`

Comment: Also, `M-x py-shell` runs the python shell as expected. The other bindings seem to work, but not `C-c !` for some reason...